# Using pluck to get unique values and store them via loop

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get the friends of the Auth user and notify them via the notifs table. I have the following query to get the friends of the Auth user :

```
        $usrusrmembs = DB::table('usrusrs')
                    ->where('accepted', 1)
                    ->where('user_id', $u_id) // $u_id is the Auth user = 4
                    ->orwhere('friend_id', $u_id)
                    ->pluck('friend_id', 'user_id');
```

The usrusrs table has one row for each friendship, where the Auth user could be the user_id or friend_id depending on who sent/received the friend request.

Vardump($usrusrmembs) will give the following for a 1 row: `array(1) { [5]=> int(4) }`

The problem is if  `$u_id` matches `friend_id` not `user_id`, only `friend_id` will be notified, but  `user_id` will not be notified.

The loop to store :

```
                foreach($usrusrmembs as $rec_users){
                      $notifs = new Notif();
                      $notifs->rec_uid = $rec_users;
                      $notifs->send_uid = $u_id;
                      $notifs->send_uname = $u_name;
                      $notifs->data_type = 9;
                      $notifs->data_id = $group_id;
                      $notifs->title = $group_title;

                       $notifs->save();
                   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this loop:

```
foreach($usrusrmembs as $key => $val){

    $rec_users = ($key == $u_id) ? $val : $key;

    $notifs = new Notif();
    $notifs->rec_uid = $rec_users;
    $notifs->send_uid = $u_id;
    $notifs->send_uname = $u_name;
    $notifs->data_type = 9;
    $notifs->data_id = $group_id;
    $notifs->title = $group_title;

    $notifs->save();
}
```

Using `pluck()` with two fields you end up with an *associative array* with the `key` as the user_id and the `value` as the friend_id. You explained that the `Auth user` could be on in the key or in the value and you want to notify the other user.

So the foreach cycle keys and values of the array (the `$key=>$value` part) and if `$key` is `$u_id` choose the `$value` to be notified, on the contrary it choose the `$key` to be notified.